# Replace Text in Bookmark

Tags: c#, ms-word, com, office-interop

I'm using Interop.Word for my app. I get the bookmarks from the doc and then i want to insert text in it. But my construction only inserts text after the bookmark:

```
    WordDocument.Bookmarks[bookmark].Select();
    WordApp.Selection.TypeText(text);
```

How can i programmatically insert within the brackets, like on the image, not replacing its bookmark? Because for now, the code inserts the text within brackets, but it deletes the bookmark itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, you'd update a bookmark with code like:

```
Sub UpdateBookmark(StrBkMk As String, StrTxt As String)
Dim BkMkRng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists(StrBkMk) Then
    Set BkMkRng = .Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range
    BkMkRng.Text = StrTxt
    .Bookmarks.Add StrBkMk, BkMkRng
  End If
End With
Set BkMkRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

which you'd call with code like:

```
Call UpdateBookmark("BookMarkName", "text to apply")
```

I'll leave it to you to do the C# adaptation.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that TypeText will insert text unless Options.ReplaceSelection is set to true. More: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/selection-typetext-method-word

Comment: Your suggestion won't help: it will remove the bookmark just the same, which is what the OP specifically wants to avoid.